# Sublime text 3 autocomplete not working correctly

Tags: sublimetext3

When I type `ul` tab, I get `<ul></ul>` 
but when I type `ul.class` tab, I get `ul.body_class`

I want it to generate `<ul class="class"></ul>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My situation is different, so I will ask a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime Text's autocomplete is working just fine. The functionality you are looking for is found in the [Emmet](http://emmet.io) plugin. You need to [install Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), then install the plugin from there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I already have Emmet installed via the Package Control.